# different IP addresses in Via and Contact header send by pjsip in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, pjsip

In my android application I have used pjsip.
Sometimes pjsip sends different IP addresses in Via and contact header of REGISTER message.
It sends its IP address in Via header (IP assigned to phone by wi-fi router) but it sends local host IP address (127.0.0.1) in contact header of REGISTER message.
Why pjsip is not sending same IP address (IP assigned to phone by wi-fi router) in both via and contact header.

Comment: this problem sometimes occurs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes pjsip fails to get ip address and use local host ip address. To solve this problem I have read ip address from java code and passed it to library.

Comment: If you could kindly share, how have you passed IP address to library? that would be great.

Comment: Currently, I don't have the code to share and also not working on it. 
But you can pass it using JNI.